# How to use bootstrap grid with system for slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to attach slider on **Home** page.But that slider should work according to the **Bootstrap**.

My `code` for slider :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="flexslider flexslider-7-<?php echo $blocks['bannerslider_id'] ?> col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 "  >
    <ul class="slides"> 
    <?php foreach ($banners as $banner): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $banner['click_url']?>" target="<?php echo $this->getTarget($banner['tartget'])?>" onclick="bannerClicks('<?php echo $banner['banner_id'] ?>','<?php echo $blocks['bannerslider_id'] ?>')" style="display:block"><img alt="<?php echo $banner['image_alt'];?>" src="<?php echo $this->getBannerImage($banner['image']); ?>"/></a>
            </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>        
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to make this **Responsive**.

But after it, just vice versa.Its behavior is complete opposite from my expectation

I need to know one slider **example** using Bootstrap and What changes should I do in this code to make it responsive ?

Comment: Is this code working ? Can you show me an example on [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new) Without PHP ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try based on bootstraps carousel plugin:

Following is a tad modified based on [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php foreach ($banners as $banner): ?>
        <div class="item active">
          <img alt="<?php echo $banner['image_alt'];?>" src="<?php echo $this->getBannerImage($banner['image']); ?>"/>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <?php echo "some caption"; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Note, you will need to add some PHP inside the `.carousel-indicators`